# How to Sql Update Into with variables in python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-update, python-3.7

The connection and all the other sql executions are working fine, but my update statement not:

```
sql= "UPDATE table_name SET column2=%s, column3=%s WHERE column1=%s;"
values = (variable2, variable3, variable1)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

The output is none.

Comment: update sql just return effected rows etc. info, you can look into table to check whether its data is changed

Comment: As of documentation on [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15): *Return values are not defined.* So it is not clear what do you expect to have as returned data.

Comment: Ive checked the table in pgAamin and no updates were made.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to update the sql entries ist the "INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT" function.

```py
cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO tablename
            (column1, column2, column3)
            VALUES
                (%s, %s, %s)
            ON CONFLICT(column1) DO UPDATE
            SET
                column2=excluded.column2,
                column3=excluded.column3;
                   """, (Value1, Value2, Value3)
                       )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with f strings.

```py
sql= f"UPDATE table_name SET column2={variable2}, column3={variable3} WHERE column1={variable1};"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: It is very bad advice to use string concatenation, bind variables are invented for safety.